# How to use SSL-certificates to call https://localhost with apache2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: apache, https, raspberry-pi, localhost

So I am currently working on a project where I use the Instagram API to get some user Data onto my Localhost webpage on the Raspberry. The API however needs secure redirect uri (https). But when the API wants do redirect to https://localhost/instagram it says
**"404 Not Found The requested URL /instagram was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) Server at localhost Port 443"**
In the url-bar it says *"Not secure"*, the https part is marked red and is crossed out. When I test my stuff on another computer which has Xampp and Apache running everything works fine and even if I type https://localhost it redirects straight to localhost.
I found out that I might need a SSL certificate in order to make use of https links even if I'm running on localhost. But I don't really know how I should do this on my raspberryPi. There are already some SSL modules enabled inside the Apache2 folder.

---